# It can't access the sdcard after setting "android.uid.system" in my application?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-manifest

This is a strange problem. My Application can access the sdcard successfully if I don't set `android.uid.system` to it. But after setting `android.uid.system` to it, my application can't access the sdcard. At this time, the exception take place:`07-13 09:11:24.999: INFO/System.out(9986): create file happen exception--->java.io.IOException: Permission denied`. I check I write the right permission in the right place:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />.
```

Because  use `forceStopPackage` in my application, I need to add `android.uid.system` to the manifest. And I have written `LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform` in the make file. Who can explain this strange problem. After setting `android.uid.system`, my application is belong the system process which should have more power to access the sdcard. This is my idea. The following are my code:

```
public void setPackage(String dir){

        System.out.println( "setPackage dir=="+dir  );
        File share=new File("/mnt/sdcard","test.txt");
        if(!share.exists()){
             try{
            share.createNewFile();

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println( "creat file happen exception--->" +e.toString() );
        }
      }
         try{
           if(share!=null){
                System.out.println( "create file is not null"  );
                    FileOutputStream fops=new FileOutputStream(share);

                    fops.write(dir.getBytes());
                    fops.flush();
                    fops.close();
        }
        }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println( "write Exception-->" +e.toString() );
        }

    }
```

And My application run at the emulator and his target version is 2.3. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please read this: [link1](http://groups.google.com/group/android-porting/browse_thread/thread/c6af65d7ddd5eff3)

and this [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617797/android-shared-user-id-and-reading-writing-a-file)

Comment: At the last, I modify my code: The access sdcard function is put in a application without system user id, and the `forceStopPackage` is put in another application with system user id. So this problem can be fixed. Thank you!

Comment: While this is the issue, it would be helpful to say something here and not merely provide links.  For legacy reasons, the system user is not permitted to access potentially removable filesystems, as all processes with an open file handle can have to be killed when the filesystem is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()` to get the path, NOT `"/mnt/sdcard"`

Comment: the issue is that the system user is not allowed to access removable filesystems.

Answer (score 0):

Use: `File share = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(),"test.txt");`

This won't work: `File share = new File("/mnt/sdcard", "test.txt");`

Comment: I modify my code according you advise, but the result is same: it also happen the 'permission denied' exception.

Comment: Indeed, this will not work - the issue is that the system user is not allowed to access removable filesystems.

Answer (score 0):

You can see in android source code: frameworks\base\core\java\android\os\Environment.java, it have a function:

```
private static void throwIfSystem() {
    if (Process.myUid() == Process.SYSTEM_UID) {
        Log.wtf(TAG, "Static storage paths aren't available from AID_SYSTEM", new Throwable());
    }
}
```

This function would be called `getExternalStorageDirectory()`, hence app with system uid can't access sdcard if you don't hack aosp.

Answer (score -1):

android.uid.system make your app bind system, but sdcard observered by system also, then if your app delete this, it can access the sdcard. it seems

delete this line in your xml file :android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"ystem